# Is $\beta\omega$ hereditarily irresolvable?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

$X$ is called *resolvable* if it can be represented as a union of two disjoint dense sets, it is *irresolvable* otherwise. Moreover it is *hereditarily irresolvable* (HI) if every subspace of X is irresolvable. My question is whether the space $\beta\omega$ is HI? I could not find the right way to approach this question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like very few spaces are hereditarily irresolvable. For example if $X$ is Hausdorff then for any $a,b \in X$ the doubleton $\{a,b\}$ is a discrete subspace and so has no proper dense subspaces. We conclude Hausdorff spaces are not hereditarily irresolvable.

Therefore $\beta \omega$ is not hereditary irresolvable. Indeed  $\beta \omega$ is resolvable. To see this let $A \subset \beta \omega$ be the set of ultrafilters of some fixed nontrivial type and $B = \beta \omega - A$. Then $A$ and $B$ are dense, disjoint, and union to the whole space.

**Edit:** This answer makes very little sense.

Comment: Indeed, $X$ need only be $T_1$. For the resolvability of $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ there is also the result by Hewitt that if $X$ is infinite and $T_1$, and the weight of $X$ is at most the minimum cardinality of a non-empty open subset of $X$, then $X$ is resolvable iff it has no isolated points.

Comment: I don't get it. $\{a,b\}$ has no proper dense subspace, therefore it is irresulvable, right? So how does that show that $X$ is not hereditarily irresolvable? Why isn't every discrete space hereditarily irresolvable? And how can a space which has isolated points, like $ \beta\omega,$ be resolvable?

Comment: You are correct. The first paragraph in fact shows that $T_1$ spaces are not "hereditary resolvable". So the first paragraph does not apply to the second. But the second remains valid.

Comment: The second paragraph in fact shows the subspace $\beta \omega - \omega$ is resolvable. So $\beta \omega $ is not hereditary irresolvable.